# mysql condition inside IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Hi I am writing mysql/oracle database query to support select all for in clause my query goes something like this

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE 
country_id in( IF('test' = 'test',(1,2,3),true) )
```

If condition ('test' = 'test') is true then it should fire query like

```
SELECT * FROM country WHERE  country_id in(1,2,3)
```

Else it should fire query

```
 SELECT * FROM country WHERE  country_id in(true)
```

Comment: Ok then what's the point ?

Comment: Any question or problem? Did you just wanted us to know that?

Comment: What's the sense: `in (true)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `test` as variable here, if `test1 = test2` then `country_id` will be in `(1,2,3)` else there will be no limited for `country_id`:

```
SELECT * FROM country
WHERE ((test1 = test2 and country_id in(1,2,3))or
        test1 <> test2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with basic boolean logic.  What you are doing is equivalent to:

```
SELECT *
FROM country
WHERE country_id in (1,2,3) or 'test' <> 'test';
```

(Note:  I am not testing for `NULL` on `'test'` because it is a literal value.  If this is really a variable that can take on a `NULL` value, you would have to take that into account as well.)